# Same results with "root" and "master", when using tkinter. Then, when to use each one?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working with Tkinter to make a user interface.
I do not understand the difference between "master" and "root".

I found some information here: [Python interface to Tcl/Tk¶](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html)

> To get at the toplevel window that contains a given widget, you can often just refer to the widget’s master. Of course if the widget has been packed inside of a frame, the master won’t represent a toplevel window. To get at the toplevel window that contains an arbitrary widget, you can call the _root() method. This method begins with an underscore to denote the fact that this function is part of the implementation, and not an interface to Tk functionality.

But I still do not understand. So I made some code, but I do not see any difference in the results obtained (***).

USING "MASTER"

```
from tkinter import *
master = Tk()   ***
Canvas = Canvas(master)   ***
Canvas.pack()

def create_circle(x, y, r, canvas): 
    x0 = x - r
    y0 = y - r
    x1 = x + r
    y1 = y + r
    return canvas.create_oval(x0, y0, x1, y1)

create_circle(100, 100, 20, Canvas)
master.mainloop()   ***
```

USING "ROOT"

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()   ***
Canvas = Canvas(root)   ***
Canvas.pack()

def create_circle(x, y, r, canvas): 
    x0 = x - r
    y0 = y - r
    x1 = x + r
    y1 = y + r
    return canvas.create_oval(x0, y0, x1, y1)

create_circle(100, 100, 20, Canvas)
root.mainloop()   ***
```

Comment: `master` seems to be just the parent of the current widget, while `root` is the root widget. If your current widget is deep in the three, master and root will be different.

Comment: Ah, in your code you are using the variable name `master` to refer to the root widget, hence the confusion. Every widget has a `master` property that will give you its parent. When you have one deep in the tree, it's parent will not be the root widget.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am working with Tkinter to make a user interface. I do not understand the difference between "master" and "root".

There is no difference. It's just a name, you can call it whatever you want.

Since tkinter widgets exist in a tree which has a single widget as its root, `root` is the official name of this widget. Because of that, `root` has become the most common name for the variable used to access this widget. However, you are free to give it any name you want, because the name is only a convenience for you. Tkinter doesn't care what you call it.

Tkinter documentation also sometimes refers to masters and slaves, and sometimes parents and children. With the exception of the root window, all widgets have a master (or parent). This terminology is used mostly in the context of the geometry managers `pack`, `place`, and `grid` as a way to describe how to put one widget inside another.

Comment: There is also an internal (but very useful) function called `._root()` which finds the master of the current widget until it gets to the very top. It's useful in case you have multiple windows with `tkinter` and `threading` (though not um... preferable).

Answer (score 0):

I would just be carefull to use master, see below ;)

Here the entire story....https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2010-June/076444.html

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

Canvas = Canvas(root)

print(dir(Canvas.master))

Canvas.pack()

def create_circle(x, y, r, canvas): 
     x0 = x - r
     y0 = y - r
     x1 = x + r
     y1 = y + r
     return canvas.create_oval(x0, y0, x1, y1)

create_circle(100, 100, 20, Canvas)

root.mainloop()
```